# wpf radcombobox scrollbar down arrow closing dropdown

Tags: wpf, radcombobox

I am using radcombobox autocomplete. The values are populating and working ok but when I am trying to scroll up or down with scrollbar arrows the combobox dropdown got closed. I checked online but found no fix.